# 'Error on Page' while running Selenium script in IE8

Tags: selenium

I am trying to run Selenium Webdriver script in IE8 and soon as the page load is complete I am getting 'Error on Page', which eventually stops the execution of the script. Please note that if I launch the same URL manually, I don't see any error.

This is what I have tried so far

> - Unchecked Enable Protected Mode

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);
driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(capabilities);
driver.get(AppURL);
driver.navigate().to("javascript:document.getElementById('overridelink').click()");
```

Nothing worked so far, however my script runs perfectly for FF and Chrome.

Please let me know if there is any possible solution to this issue, I am using Windows 7

Comment: What is the error you are seeing on the page after loading is completed?

Answer (score 1):

This is expected. Selenium won't run properly unless you have the protected mode disabled in the internet explorer options.
Disable it and it should work fine.